# Is the a easy way to print the :e format to 10^x format?

Tags: python, format

I am writing some numerical value in a matplotlib textbox as

```
  textst = "$En_1={0:.4e}$".format(
      *popt)
  plt.text(.950,
           .100,
           textst,
           bbox=props,
           ha='right',
           va='bottom',
           transform=ax.transAxes)
```

Problem is, I am getting the numerical value as,say, `5 e +5`. I want the value as `5x10^5`, i.e. proper superscript.

Is there any easy way of doing this? (easy is the key here, I don't want a lot of regex etc to get the `e->10` etc)

Comment: Regexes were invented to make certain tasks easier.  This might be one of them, but I'll never put in the effort to figure it out since you've so rudely ruled them out.

Comment: _"Easy"_ is a subjective term. You don't need _regex_ to replace `"e"` with `"\\times 10^"`

Comment: For what it's worth given that this is going on a visualization, just know that most people prefer to read the `"e"` syntax when "proper" superscript isn't actually available.

Comment: Unless you actually want something that can be interpreted as LaTeX, in which case you should specify that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do it yourself. Note that I'm assuming you want something that can be interpreted as LaTeX:

```py
import math


def custom_number_format(n: float, precision: int = 3) -> str:
    exp = math.floor(math.log10(n))
    decimal = round(n / 10**exp, precision)
    return rf"{decimal} \times 10^{{{exp}}}"  # or f"{decimal}x10^{exp}" if you don't want LaTeX
```

Demo:

```py
In [3]: for i in range(-11, 11):
   ...:     print(custom_number_format(1.23456789 * 10**i, 4))
   ...:
1.2346 \times 10^{-11}
1.2346 \times 10^{-10}
1.2346 \times 10^{-9}
1.2346 \times 10^{-8}
1.2346 \times 10^{-7}
1.2346 \times 10^{-6}
1.2346 \times 10^{-5}
1.2346 \times 10^{-4}
1.2346 \times 10^{-3}
1.2346 \times 10^{-2}
1.2346 \times 10^{-1}
1.2346 \times 10^{0}
1.2346 \times 10^{1}
1.2346 \times 10^{2}
1.2346 \times 10^{3}
1.2346 \times 10^{4}
1.2346 \times 10^{5}
1.2346 \times 10^{6}
1.2346 \times 10^{7}
1.2346 \times 10^{8}
1.2346 \times 10^{9}
1.2346 \times 10^{10}
```

Or use regex, because the pattern is pretty straight forward, although you lose the ability to set the precision dynamically:

```py
import re

p = re.compile(r"(\d\.\d{4})e[\+\-](\d*)")


def custom_number_format(n: float) -> str:
    decimal, exponent = p.match(f"{n}:.4e").groups()
    return rf"{decimal} \times 10^{{{int(exponent)}}}")
```

Answer (score 0):

*"proper superscript"* (use appropriate font )

```py
import math

super = str.maketrans('-0123456789',
                      '\N{SUPERSCRIPT MINUS}'
                      '\N{SUPERSCRIPT ZERO}'
                      '\N{SUPERSCRIPT ONE}'
                      '\N{SUPERSCRIPT TWO}'
                      '\N{SUPERSCRIPT THREE}'
                      '\N{SUPERSCRIPT FOUR}'
                      '\N{SUPERSCRIPT FIVE}'
                      '\N{SUPERSCRIPT SIX}'
                      '\N{SUPERSCRIPT SEVEN}'
                      '\N{SUPERSCRIPT EIGHT}'
                      '\N{SUPERSCRIPT NINE}')

def myexp(n):
    exponent = math.floor(math.log10(n))
    mantissa = n / 10**exponent
    return f'{mantissa:.4}\N{MULTIPLICATION SIGN}10{str(exponent).translate(super)}'

for i in range(20):
    n = 1.23456 * 10**i
    print(myexp(n))
```

```
1.2346×10⁰
1.2346×10¹
1.2346×10²
1.2346×10³
1.2346×10⁴
1.2346×10⁵
1.2346×10⁶
1.2346×10⁷
1.2346×10⁸
1.2346×10⁹
1.2346×10¹⁰
1.2346×10¹¹
1.2346×10¹²
1.2346×10¹³
1.2346×10¹⁴
1.2346×10¹⁵
1.2346×10¹⁶
1.2346×10¹⁷
1.2346×10¹⁸
1.2346×10¹⁹
```

Comment: lol well played